# Why is my Nether portal warping effect messed up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing in my world and then when I tried to go into a Nether portal, I experienced this weird glitch:

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you describe the problem in the body of your question? Answers that are link-only are closed for this reason, so I take it questions should as well (in case the link disappears, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your game has been corrupted, leading to the messed up distortion of your nether portal's warped effect.

As for fixing the issue, try restarting your Minecraft. If the issue persists, <s>consult the doctor</s> check the game files and see what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

When you walk into a Nether portal, there is a world-warping visual effect. It seems in your case that this effect has glitched out—but this is irrelevant to gameplay, a mere annoyance rather than a real obstacle, and if you stand inside the portal long enough, you will go through anyway.

Without some rather arduous debugging, which would probably require the assistance of Mojang employees and which I'm sure none of us have designs on doing in any case, we can only speculate as to the cause, and therefore only speculate as to the fix—but my money would be on one of the following:

- Your graphics card is being weird. Try updating or reinstalling your graphics drivers, or getting a different graphics card.
- You have a mod installed that tries to do something weird with shaders or the graphics pipeline (e.g. Optifine). Get rid of it and see if you still have the problem on vanilla.

Comment: He’s asking how to fix it.

Comment: @Dabbingsdednow not at the time of posting. I edited that in so its more on-topic for this site, otherwise it might get closed because it seems more like a bug report than a question

Comment: @Dabbingsdednow And he's asking why it is happening.